# Swing doesn't open the window, even when the code works fine on terminal

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, window

I wanted to create a program that generates a random number and I must find the mystery number. That works great. Next  I wanted to make it in a window to learn GUI & Swing, not in the terminal, so i used some Swing code.
But here is the issue, the code still works fine in the terminal, but it doesn't open a window like I want.

First, IO tried to create a second class for the GUI part, but it didn't work, so I grouped everything in the main method. It works in terminal but doesn't open the window.

Any help or tips please ?

```
/**
 * Auteur Andres "VongoSanDi" Boulanger
 */

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ChiffreMystere {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numeroMin = 0, numeroMax = 0, entreeUtilisateur = 0;
        char rejouer = 'O';

        System.out.println("Bienvenue au jeu du chiffre mystère\n");

        do {

            System.out.println("Veuillez choisir un minimum et un maximum pour le jeu.");
            System.out.print("Minimum : ");
            numeroMin = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Maximum : ");
            numeroMax = sc.nextInt();

            int chiffreMystere = (int)(Math.random() * ((numeroMax - numeroMin) + 1)) + numeroMin;

            System.out.print("\nSelon vous, quel est le chiffre mystère : ");

            while(entreeUtilisateur != chiffreMystere) {
                entreeUtilisateur = sc.nextInt();

                if (entreeUtilisateur != chiffreMystere) {
                    System.out.println("\nCe n'est pas le bon chiffre.");
                    System.out.print("Quel est le chiffre mystère ? : ");
                }

            }

            System.out.println("\nBravo, vous avez trouvé le chiffre mystère, qui était le : "+chiffreMystere);

            System.out.print("Voulez-vous rejouer ? (O/N) : ");
            rejouer = sc.next().charAt(0);

        } while(rejouer == 'O');

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chiffre mystère");
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(100,200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Finally I would like to create a second class only for the GUI part and be able to call it from the main method.

Comment: I would guess your frame doesn't display because it is never executed because the looping code never finished. Did you add a System.out.println(...) before you try to display the frame to see if that statement gets executed? A Swing program is completely different than a terminal program. Forget about your terminal program and start over, Start by just displaying an empty JFrame. .Then if you want to prompt the user for data you use a JOptionPane.

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). There are sections on `How to Make Frames` and `How to Make Dialogs` with examples to get you started.